# Добавление данных в БД с помощью js

Tags: javascript, ajax

Пытаюсь с помощью ajax'a добавить значение текстового поля в БД, но получаю ошибки, вот код.
Поле и кнопка:

```
<div class="profile__country profile__country--v">
    <select id="category" class="support__selector"  name="Country">
        <option value="">US</option>
        <option value="">2</option>
        <option value="">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="btn btn-v-1" style="margin-top:30px" type="text" onclick='SaveCuntry();'>
    Upload
</div>
```

Функция

```
<script>
    function SaveCuntry(){
       var Country = document.getElementById('category').value;
       $.ajax({
           url: 'Country.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {Country:Country},
           success: function(res){
               $('.alert').css('background',res.color)
               Alert_Opoveshenie(res.message);
           },
           error: function(){
               $('.alert').css('background','red')
               Alert_Opoveshenie('Error!');
           }
       });
   }

   function Alert_Opoveshenie(Text){
       document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = Text;
       $('.alert').animate({
           bottom: '10px',
           opacity: '1'
       },1000,function(){
           // После показа убираем его
           var alertHide = setInterval(function(){
               $('.alert').animate({
                   bottom: '-100%',
                   opacity: '0'
               },1000);
               clearInterval(alertHide);
           },2000); // Время "жизни" алерта 2 секунды.
       });
    }   
</script>
```

и файл country

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors','Off');
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        include_once('db.php');
        $Country = $_POST['Country'];
        $sesion_id=$_SESSION['userid'];

        if ($mysqli->query("UPDATE Verification SET country='$Country' WHERE id='$sesion_id'")){
            $message = 'Successful!';
            $color = 'green';
            $out = array(
                'message' => $message,
                'color' => $color
            );

            header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');
            echo json_encode($out);
            die;
        }
        else{
            $message = 'Error saving!';
            $color = 'red';
            $out = array(
                'message' => $message,
                'color' => $color
            );

            header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');
            echo json_encode($out);
            die;
        }
    }
    else{
        $message = 'Session Error!';
        $color = 'red';
        $out = array(
            'message' => $message,
            'color' => $color
        );

        header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo json_encode($out);
        die;
    }
?>
```

В консоли получаю ошибки

```
jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 POST    Country.php 404
send @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
SaveCuntry @ profile-v-3.php:193
onclick @ profile-v-3.php:175


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at Alert_Opoveshenie (profile-v-3.php:211)
    at Object.error (profile-v-3.php:203)
    at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

Comment: `var FullN = document.getElementById('FullN').value;`

Comment: @mix значение добавляет, но посыпались другие ошибки `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at Alert_Opoveshenie (profile-v-2.php:207)
    at Object.success (profile-v-2.php:195)
    at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)`

Comment: В коде ничего нет про тег с `id="alert"`, следовательно помочь не могу.

Comment: "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" все же написано - свойство innerHTML вызывается у  null, соответствен не правильно выбран элемент

Comment: @mix можете посмотреть вопрос, попытался добавить в БД значение из выпадающего меню, но опять ошибки

Comment: @Midnight, новые ошибки? Если все то же `Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`, то вам уже ответили: проблема в том, что у вас нет на странице элемента с id="alert", по этому `document.getElementById("alert")` будет равно `null`, а у `null` нет свойства `innerHTML`. Если проблема в чем-то ещё, опишите её (желательно исправив вопрос, а не в комментариях)

Comment: @MedvedevDev так я поправил вопрос

Comment: @Midnight, так а ошибки то какие? В вопросе ошибка одна, по поводу причины её возникновения вам уже ответили, в чем затруднение то?